# How do I save data from websocket?

Tags: python, pandas, websocket

I have successfully subscribed to a websocket and am receiving data. I am waiting to save my data so I can use it in a data frame for further analysis.

My code so far is only returning empty lists and dataframes.

Code:
**RETURNS EMPTY LIST**

```
wsClient = GDAX.WebsocketClient(url="wss://ws-feed.gdax.com", products="LTC-USD")

df1 = []

for i in wsClient.start():
    df1 = df1.append(wsClient.start())
```

Code:
**RETURNS EMPTY LIST AND DATAFRAME**

```
wsClient = GDAX.WebsocketClient(url="wss://ws-feed.gdax.com", products="LTC-USD")


dfs = []
for i in wsClient.start():
    dfs.append(wsClient.start())
df1 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `wsClient.start()` twice?

Comment: if I only try 'wsClient' as is in the 'for' line, I get an error "TypeError: 'WebsocketClient' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement your own custom `on_message` method to be able to get the `websocket` information:

```
import time
import gdax
import pandas as pd

results = []

class myWebsocketClient(gdax.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url = "wss://ws-feed.gdax.com/"
        self.products = ["LTC-USD"]

    def on_message(self, msg):
        if 'price' in msg and 'type' in msg:
            results.append(msg['price'])

wsClient = myWebsocketClient()
wsClient.start()

time.sleep(5)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ["Price"])
print(df.head())
wsClient.close()
```

This will run for 5 seconds, and outputs:

```
          Price
0  153.13000000
1  151.14000000
2  140.52000000
3  140.52000000
4  152.62000000

-- Socket Closed --
```